# custom class initializers with ARC - self.name or name?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, memory-management

when defining a Person class with ARC,

1. should i use **self.fullname** or just **fullname** in the initializer?
2. if i use **fullname** will the passed strings be retained?
3. if i use **self.fullname** i must define a setter or a property? should i use **strong**?

[image: Person class initializer]

coming from a pre ARC way of thinking, i'm trying to wrap my head around the changes ARC suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. With ARC, these behave the same way, except that `self.fullname` will pass through the setter. The default setter will give you KVO-compliance. But otherwise, there is no difference.
2. Yes they will, if the pointers have been declared strong.
3. To use `self.fullname = ...` you must define a setter. For NSStrings and other classes which have mutable variants, it is usually recommended to use `(copy)`.

Comment: so would you recommend:

 "@property (copy) NSString *fullName;" as a property?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Usually properties are a good idea if you want the value to be accessible from a different class (otherwise, there is no need for it).

Comment: Properties (= synthesized accessors with a getter & setter) are always a good idea, even if you do not access them from the outside.

Comment: @auco Why do you say that? If you don't need external access and you don't need KVO-compliance then properties/accessors are just adding extra overhead. I don't believe they are thread-safe.

Comment: @jtbandes: of course they may be thread-save (depending on the object implementation of course), that's why you can specify (atomic/nonatomic). Properties mainly help you to save a lot of typing. If you consider a class with 500+ lines, then (conceptually) it makes no difference if you're accessing your properties/ivars from the internal or external. There is potential to mess it up. Accessors are just good practice. I doubt there are a lot of use cases where the performance overhead of calling a couple of additional accessor methods is better than applying good programming practice.

Answer (score 2):

In initializers, I'd advise *against* invoking any methods on `self`, because the object is in that unusual state where it lacks self-consistency. For the simple example you give, it doesn't make a difference right away. But if you later define your own `-setFullname:` method that reads or writes any other part of your object, invoking `self.fullname =` from your initializer will cause problems because the object isn't fully-formed yet.

Comment: but if i set the property of a iVar to copy. it won't copy unless i use self - or will it?

Comment: Just do it yourself: `fullname = [name copy];`

Answer (score 2):

I think the available answers need some clarification.

### The long answer to your question

Look at this header:

```
Person : NSObject {
    NSString *name; // better to call this _name to not confuse it with the property
    // and even more better to not use an ivar, but only a property
}

@property (strong) NSString *name;
```

1. You have an instance variable. Usually you'd call your ivar the same as the property with an underscore, but often you'll find the ivar and the property have the same name.
2. It is also possible to *only* declare a property, in this case, the compiler will *automatically* insert an ivar with an underscore for you!

Now it is important to understand, that there is one major difference between `name = @"John Smith"` and `self.name = @"John Smith"`, the first one directly sets the instance variable (aka `_name = @"John Smith"`, disregarding memory management and (without ARC) creating a leak if the former value was not nil. Using the self-dot-syntax (self.name) uses the *automatically generated accessor* (=setter method), which respects the chosen memory management (typically retain or strong or copy).

Before properties and before ARC an object setter would have looked like this:

```
-(void)setName:(NSString*)newName {
    if(newName != name) {
        [name release];
        name = newName;
        [newName retain];
    }
}
```

that means, the old iVar value is released and the new iVar value retained. All balanced and fine.

Now, with ARC and synthesized accessors (properties), you do not have to care about all this. While Properties synthesize acessors, ARC synthesizes and balanced retain/release calls based on an analysis of your code. So ARC and properties are not necessarily requiring each other, because they synthesize different aspects (note for example the different syntax "__weak" at the ivar declaration and "(weak)" at the property declaration?). But it's useful to know how it used to work, because now you'll see that there is a major difference between

```
name = @"John Smith"; // directly access ivar, the old value is never released 
// your program is leaking if you're not using ARC
```

and going through the synthesized accessor

```
self.name = @"John Smith"; // old ivar released, new ivar set, all okay
```

### The short answer to your question

1. do not use an ivar *and* a property if there is no need for both
2. self.property = newValue sets the new value by its setter method
3. ivar = newValue sets the new value directly, bypassing any setter method
4. it is definitely recommended to use the accessors and to not set ivars directly if there is a setter method (in other words: if you have a property, use its setter by calling self.property = newValue)

Comment: it's good to know the compiler will automatically insert an ivar with an underscore for me. i didn't know that. regarding my question - i wanted to know how the ARC deals with accessing the iVars directly. i mean if i create a new person class like that: [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"James"] - it means the @"James" string is autoreleased - and i am not retaining it... i understand the difference between self.name and name and i guess in initializers it's less important because there is no previous value.

Comment: @Guy: Typically, you'd expect that -initWithName: uses self.name=@"James". It doesn't really matter if it's an initializer or not, it's a question of who "owns" the object (owners retain when they create the obj & release when they destroy it; others retain & autorelease their values). But: luckily with ARC, you do not have to worry about this anymore. As a general thumb of rule: if there is a property, use it. Do not access an ivar directly, disrespecting the setter. AFAIK ARC does not deal with ivars: Properties synthesize accessors and ARC synthesizes and balances retain/release calls.